# Iterative regex in Python: find and replace

Tags: python, regex, foreach

This is one of those "I'd know how to do it in C" type questions. :p
 I'm asking this as similar questions in SO don't have a particular aspect I'm looking for.

I'm essentially looking to find and replace items that also have possessive forms. So if there is a "rabbit" in the list, and also a "rabbit's", then replace "rabbit" with a series of asterisks.

Something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

text = open("list.txt", "w")

for line in text:
        test = line
        if re.match(test+"'", line) or re.match(test+"'s", line):
            line = "****"
```

However, this clearly won't work as the for each mechanism makes line be used for both iteration and pattern matching.

Comment: You probably want to open the file in read mode.

Comment: can your so your input data???

Comment: `test = line` and then `re.match(test+"'", line)`, how is that supposed to work?

Comment: `line = "****"` does nothing in this case, variable is recreated in the loop for each element.

Comment: BenjaminToueg; Rusty : See last line of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    # Remove the \n characters at the end of each line
    all_lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
    for line in all_lines:
        # Check for presence of word' or word's 
        if line+"'" in all_lines or line+"'s" in all_lines:
            print('****')
        else:
            print(line)
```

It's worth noting that this is quite a brute force way of doing and for huge lists will take a bit longer (it loads the file into memory) but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.endswith:`

```
text = open("list.txt", "r")

for line in text:
    test = line.strip()
    if test.endswith("'s"):
        line = "****"
```

Here i have explained why your code is not going to work:

replace this:

```
test = line
```

to:

```
test = line.strip()   # to remove new line character
```

so your test will be `rabbit\n'`, if you don't remove newline character

you also need to open file on read mode

```
text = open("list.txt",'r')
```

you match is not going to work, think of it:

suppose test="rabbit's"

```
    test+"'" will give you `rabbit's'`
```